# CKEditor Browse server gives wrong URL

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ImageUploader plugin in CKEditor, when I press on Image button and then Browse server, it opens a page that doesn;t exist url is:

```
mycurrentUrl/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php?CKEditor=content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
```

Which doesn't exist cause it appends /ckeditor/... part to my current url, not to my base URL. correct url would be

```
address.com/backend/js/plugins/imageuploader/imgbrowser.php...
```

I tried to set Editor Path, Base path but it doesnt help. I also tried to set

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/backend/files';
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/browser/browse.php';
```

in my config.js file but it seems that it doesn't react to these changes.

How can I set a correct url?

Comment: You set up this in config.js ? Is other setting work from config.js ?